# How to test mysql's max_execution_time option in django using pytest

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, pytest

I'm trying to test `max_execution_time` option of mysql in Django with pytest. But I'm having trouble with making slow query to test the option with pytest. Can you give me any tips or good example of slow query?

## Environment

- Python 3.8.10
- Django 3.0.14
- pytest 5.4.3
- MySQL 5.7

## Tried

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_max_execution_time():
    with pytest.raise(OperationalError):
        result = list(Blog.objects.raw("""
            CREATE PROCEDURE InfLoop()
            BEGIN
            WHILE 1=1 DO
                SELECT 1;
            END WHILE;
            END;
            CALL InfLoop();
        """))
```

```sh
pytest test.py
```

## Actual

```
FAILED test.py F
===================================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________ test_max_execution_time _______________________________________________________________________

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_max_execution_time():
        with pytest.raises(OperationalError):
>           result = list(Blog.objects.raw("""
            CREATE PROCEDURE InfLoop()
            BEGIN
            WHILE 1=1 DO
                SELECT 1;
            END WHILE;
            END;
            CALL InfLoop();
        """))
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'django.db.utils.OperationalError'>

test.py:102: Failed
============================================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================================
FAILED test.py::test_max_execution_time - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class'django.db.utils.OperationalError'>
```

## Expected

```
1 passed
```

Comment: Much shorter test case:  `SELECT SLEEP(9999);`

Comment: MySQL has no practical way to catch a long-running query.  (MariaDB does.)